# Adapting a programmer CV to general work?

Tags: resume, career-switch, burnout

I worked as an Android Developer for a few years (it was the only work I ever did, from the age of 19 to 23), as such my CV is composed of 3 Android roles and nothing else. Doing this work has ultimately had a detrimental affect on my health. I experienced quite a severe burnout in my last role and after more than a year have still not recovered, finding it difficult to understand even basic instructions without difficulty etc.

As such I am now looking for simpler work (e.g. factory work, manual labor) as I need to start making an income again. How can I adapt my CV for applying for these types of roles? How much detail should I give about my previous positions? I imagine there will be a lot of questions about why I'm no longer pursuing a career in programming and why the gaps in time etc. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your skills won't translate, but you can still list your development experience.  I did something similar when I was struggling to find work in development and listed my skills.  I was hired at a warehouse fairly easily without much push back on why.  Just know that you'll quickly become the go-to guy for any computer systems or technical issues that may arise.  I found that my technical background helped me quickly adapt as a skilled forklift driver and I was called on to improve efficiency and organization of product in the warehouse.

Answer (score 7):

I made a career change about 8 years ago from IT to a much different field.

I did include my IT career on my resume simply because it is a work history -- it showed I could keep a job, etc.

Just recently (6 months) I lost my job and have had to fall back on my IT career until I find a new job in my new field.   I was completely open and honest in the interview and told them I'd likely move back into it at some point, but planned to be in this position at least a year.

If you get asked about it in an interview, tell them you determined that line of work wasn't for you and you want a change.  Perhaps someday you MIGHT go back (as they will wonder), but it will likely be awhile before you do.   Maybe you never plan to go back -- but you need to communicate that you plan on doing that job for awhile -- long enough to make it worth their while to hire and train you.

AS for adapting the resume?    List the jobs, but don't necessarily list every technology you used.   Emphasize the skills you have that would be applicable to the job you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Hiring managers are generally trying to answer two questions when they evaluate a candidate:

- **Does this person have the skills that the position requires?** This one is obvious, and in your case, there is probably little that applies in terms of skills overlap between programming Android apps and doing manual labor.
- **Will this person be a *good* employee?** This one is a little more vague and hard to define, but it's comprised of typical soft skills (can this person communicate? Can they follow directions? Will they mesh well with our team?) and also general employee-quality concepts (will this person be on time every day? Will this person leave right after we've invested in their training?)

Although your programming skills may not transfer, showing you have work history can help you answer the second question, at least - you can show that you're employable, able to work on a team, able to communicate, able to dedicate yourself to completing tasks, and so on. So - write your resume to focus on those things, and use your cover letter or other vehicle to discuss the fact that you're making a career change.

If you're applying for unskilled labor positions, the good news is that you may find that the second bullet above is more important than the first.